# python как к определенному времени добавить 4 часа

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня в переменной valid_date записывается время командой

```
valid_time = time.strptime(times, '%H:%M')
```

Время вводится вручную (например 21:00)
Как к этому времени можно еще прибавить 4 часа?

Comment: в каком смысле добавить и как вручную?

Comment: А если введено 21:00, то что должно получиться после прибавления 4 часов?

Answer (score 1):

Для добавления времени использую timedelta() из встроенного модуля datetime.
Пример использования:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def main():
    current_time = datetime.now().time()
    current_timedelta = timedelta(hours=current_time.hour)
    new_timedelta = timedelta(hours=4)

    print(f"current_timedelta = {current_timedelta}")
    print(f"new_timedelta = {new_timedelta}")
    print(f"result = {current_timedelta + new_timedelta}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Результат:

```
current_timedelta = 22:00:00
new_timedelta = 4:00:00
result = 1 day, 2:00:00
```